# Scale an UIView except one of its subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, cgaffinetransformscale

I'm scaling an `UIView` this way:

```
myView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.9, 0.9);
```

and the view is scaled well, but I want one of its subview to remain unscaled, i.e fullscreen. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way is to add additional scaling for specific subview

```
myView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.9, 0.9);
specific.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 1./0.9, 1./0.9);
```

probably you will also need to add

```
myView.clipsToBounds = NO;
```

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get Avt's answer to work by using CGAffineTransformInvert:

```
myView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.9, 0.9)
subView.transform = CGAffineTransformInvert(myView.transform)
```